# Windows redirect error not working using append

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm having a weird problem that must be a matter of me doing something wrong.

When using windows command line functions I know it is possible to redirect error output using 2> nul but it is not working with the following command when I am trying to append output to a file which is intentionally read only.

```
(echo dataExample) >> C:\filename.txt 2> nul
```

I am still seeing the Access is denied message that I thought would be redirected to nul

Comment: you're directing output from the command not directing output from the directing of output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line redirects error output of command `echo` to device **NUL** which is useless as this command does not print something to **STDERR**.

The command line to use is:

```
(echo dataExample>>C:\filename.txt) 2>nul
```

`dataExample` is output by `echo` which is appended to file `C:\filename.txt`.

If the target text file is write protected, Windows command processor outputs an error message to **STDERR**. As any output to **STDERR** on execution of any command within the command block defined with the round brackets is redirected to device **NUL**, this error message is suppressed with that command line.

**Note:** A space between `dataExample` and `>>` is also written into the text file. So if no trailing space is wanted in the text file, don't specify a space left of `>>`. A space right of `>>` does not matter.

Comment: Let me suggest to put the `echo` part in parentheses on its own, like `((echo dataExample) >> C:\filename.txt) 2> nul`, so spaces in front of `>>` are no problem any more; or even better as more general: `2> nul (>> "C:\filename.txt" echo dataExample)`